# unable to loop over the href value in web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to web scraping. I need to scrape the anchor tag links of a particular section in the webpage but unfortunately, I am missing something which I couldn't find out. it's printing only one link.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page  = requests.get('https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/')
prefix = 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph' 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

container = soup.findAll("section", {"class": "news_content"})
for circulars in container:

     pdf =  prefix + circulars.div.a['href'].replace("..", "")
     print(pdf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you did a `find_all` on section but there is only one section.

You can do this:

**CODE:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page  = requests.get('https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/')
prefix = 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph' 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

section = soup.find("section", {"class": "news_content"})
for link in section.find_all("a"):
     pdf =  prefix + link['href'].replace(prefix,"").replace("..", "")
     print(pdf)
```

**RESULTS:**

```
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-01-security-of-personal-data-in-government-agencies/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-02-data-sharing-agreements-involving-government-agencies/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-03-personal-data-breach-management/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-04-rules-of-procedure/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-17-01-registration-data-processing-notifications-regarding-automated-decision-making/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/NPC17-01_Appendix-1.pdf
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-no-18-01-rules-of-procedure-on-requests-for-advisory-opinions/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-no-18-02-guidelines-on-compliance-checks/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-no-18-03-rules-on-mediation-before-the-national-privacy-commission
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page  = requests.get('https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/')
prefix = 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph' 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

container = soup.findAll("section", {"class": "news_content"})
for circulars in container:
    for a in circulars.findAll('a', href=True):
         pdf =  prefix + a['href'].replace("..", "") if prefix not in a['href'] else a['href']
         print(pdf)
```

Output

```
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-01-security-of-personal-data-in-government-agencies/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-02-data-sharing-agreements-involving-government-agencies/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-03-personal-data-breach-management/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-04-rules-of-procedure/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-17-01-registration-data-processing-notifications-regarding-automated-decision-making/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/NPC17-01_Appendix-1.pdf
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-no-18-01-rules-of-procedure-on-requests-for-advisory-opinions/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-no-18-02-guidelines-on-compliance-checks/
https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-no-18-03-rules-on-mediation-before-the-national-privacy-commission
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simplified_doc's solution, which can help you turn relative paths into full paths.

```
import requests
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
url = 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/'
page  = requests.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(page.text)
container = doc.getElement('section',attr='class',value='news_content')
lstA = container.listA(url=url)
print ([a.url for a in lstA])
```

Result:

```
['https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-01-security-of-personal-data-in-government-agencies/', 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-02-data-sharing-agreements-involving-government-agencies/', 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-03-personal-data-breach-management/', 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph/memorandum-circulars/npc-circular-16-04-rules-of-procedure/', 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-17-01-registration-data-processing-notifications-regarding-automated-decision-making/', 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/npc17-01_appendix-1.pdf', 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-no-18-01-rules-of-procedure-on-requests-for-advisory-opinions/', 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-no-18-02-guidelines-on-compliance-checks/', 'https://www.privacy.gov.ph/npc-circular-no-18-03-rules-on-mediation-before-the-national-privacy-commission']
```

You can get the examples of SimplifiedDoc [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples)